# Insert at index in linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

Why does the insert at index method not work properly? Can someone please explain. I believe I am doing it right. Or from my understanding I think, what is happening is I am assigning the previous nodes next to my index I want new data at, and the old node at the position is not getting a reference.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def add_at_beggining(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def print_list(self):
        if(self.head == None):
            print("linkedList is empty")
        else:
            curr = self.head
            while curr is not None:
                print(curr.data)
                curr = curr.next

    def add_at_end(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if(self.head == None):
            new_node = self.head
        else:
            curr = self.head
            while curr.next is not None:
                curr = curr.next
            curr.next = new_node

    def get_length(self):
        size = 0
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            size+=1
            curr = curr.next
        
        return size

    def remove_at(self,index):
        if index < 0 or index<= self.get_length():
            raise Exception("invalid input")
        
        if index == 0:
            self.head = self.head.next
            return
        count = 0
        curr = self.head
        while curr:
            if count == index -1:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
                break
            curr = curr.next
            count +=1

    def add_at_index(self,data,index):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if index < 0 or index >= self.get_length():
            raise Exception("invalid input")
        if index == 0:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node
        #code is good upto here
        count = 0
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            if count == index-1:
                new_node = curr.next
                break
            curr = curr.next 
            count +=1
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `curr.next = new_node` instead of `new_node = curr.next`?  Reassigning `new_node` just loses the node you created without changing the list.  You also need to set `new_node.next` so you don't lose the rest of the list.

Comment: inside while loop it should be curr.next = new_node. small fix but question is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `new_node` with `curr.next`. That will not modify the list. Instead you lose the reference to the new node you had created. Instead do:

```
if count == index-1:
    new_node.next = curr.next
    curr.next = new_node
    break
```

There are a few other issues:

The `if` condition at the start of `add_at_index` should allow the index to be *equal* to the length of the list, which means the insertion will happen right after the last node. So it should be:

```
    if index < 0 or index > self.get_length():
        raise Exception("invalid input")
```

In `remove_at`, that similar `if` condition is not allowing any of the good indexes to be accepted. The second condition has the comparator in the wrong direction. It should be:

```
    if index < 0 or index >= self.get_length():
        raise Exception("invalid input")
```

Comment: Thanks! Just saw this after getting solution and appreciate it. Helps clarify more.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but now I wanted to do print statements to visualize more but they wont print lol

```
def add_at_index(self,data,index):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if index < 0 or index >= self.get_length():
            raise Exception("invalid input")
        if index == 0:
            new_node.next = self.head
            self.head = new_node
        #code is good upto here
        count = 0
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            if count == index-1:
                #Need to assign old node to new node pointer
                new_node.next = curr.next
                curr.next = new_node
                break
            print("curr:" , curr)
            curr = curr.next
            count+=1
```

Comment: It seems you are asking a new question here? In that case the answer area is not the right spot to ask about this. If you still have the printing problem, then you could ask a new question about it (via "Ask Question").